# JPEG2000 in R or batch convert to geotiff

Tags: r, geospatial, cran, geotiff, jpeg2000

I am looking to open .jp2 images into R.
I have Sentinel-2 satellite imagery, but I cannot seem to get JPEG2000 GDAL drivers installed correctly or linked to my R environment. I’ve tried working with Jasper, but that didn’t work out as I hoped. 
Are there any packages that allow for direct opening of .jp2 sentinel-data in R?

Alternatively, I am trying to batch convert jp2 to geotiff, so I can work with these in R. I’ve tried this: https://viewer.nationalmap.gov/tools/rasterconversion/Convert_JP2_Data_2_GeoTIFF_with_ESRI.html but I do not have ArcGIS available, so that failed as well. 
Files need to keep their original name, only the extension has to change.

I am looking for an open-source solution that can be used on large amounts of files (several hundred at least, so doing it manual in QGIS is no solution).

Can you help me with this?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried using Cygwin by any chance? I've had a lot of issues with jpeg2000 under the windows architecture. Linux has a much better time of dealing with it, in my experience at least. You should be able to pipe a .jp2 into a .tif within Cygwin. For whatever reason the gdal libraries are more complete (I lack understanding in that area).

Comment: Thanks for the anwer. I have never worked with Cygin or Linux, so I kind of hope there is a Windows solution as well. What commands would you use with Cygwin?

Comment: Cygwin is a windows program that uses a Linux architecture, think of it as a pseudo operating system within a program. I would read in the file followed by the command `> data_to_be_tiffed.tif`. I've never read a jp2 in directly so I can't really help you there, sorry!